# Numeric array index lost once JSON API response is generated

Tags: php, laravel, api-design

I am experiencing an unexpected behaviour with Laravel 5.7 & Php 7.2 while generating a JSON REST API response.

A field in the API response contains an array numerically index but ordered on the values like this:

```
"selections" => array:3 [▼
   3 => "Barton & Guestier/ Spirit/ Brian"
   1 => "Barton & Guestier/ Wine/ Latour"
   2 => "Dom Pérignon/ Effervescent/ Champagne"
]
```

Once the field is processed by the `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource` class for encoding, the indexes are stripped from the JSON output and the array is returned as a sequential array like this:

```
"selections": [
    "Barton & Guestier/ Spirit/ Brian",
    "Barton & Guestier/ Wine/ Latour",
    "Dom Pérignon/ Effervescent/ Champagne"
],
```

Same if the array is ordered by key like this

```
"selections" => array:3 [▼
   1 => "Barton & Guestier/ Wine/ Latour"
   2 => "Dom Pérignon/ Effervescent/ Champagne"
   3 => "Barton & Guestier/ Spirit/ Brian"
```

it becomes

```
"selections": [
    "Barton & Guestier/ Wine/ Latour",
    "Dom Pérignon/ Effervescent/ Champagne"
    "Barton & Guestier/ Spirit/ Brian",
],
```

Index of the first item is no longer indexed `3` or `1` but `0`.

Problem is that I need to preserve those index as they correspond to the id of those entries in my SQL database.

I was able to locate a recursive method `filter` within the `Illuminate\Http\Resources\ConditionallyLoadsAttributes` class which seems to be clearing out any element with a numeric key.
Since it is part of the core of Laravel, I cannot alter this method.

```
    /**
     * Filter the given data, removing any optional values.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return array
     */
    protected function filter($data)
    {
        $index = -1;

        $numericKeys = array_values($data) === $data;

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $index++;

            if (is_array($value)) {
                $data[$key] = $this->filter($value);

                continue;
            }

            if (is_numeric($key) && $value instanceof MergeValue) {
                return $this->mergeData($data, $index, $this->filter($value->data), $numericKeys);
            }

            if ($value instanceof self && is_null($value->resource)) {
                $data[$key] = null;
            }
        }

        return $this->removeMissingValues($data, $numericKeys);
    }
```

Surely I'm not the first one to try to return a numeric array with a specific order or not starting at index `0`.  Is this a bug?
Anyone has experienced this and found a way around?

Comment: Can't replicate the problem https://3v4l.org/D9u5s

Comment: In JSON/JavaScript, an array is only a list of elements without explicit index. If you need indices, use an object.

Comment: Another solution: use an array with elements, where each element is a pair of [index,value].

Comment: Wiimm This is indeed what I'm doing (index => value).  Problem is the index in a numerical value generated by the SQL database.  Your idea of using an object instead of an array nailed it!  Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wiimm!
Using an object instead of an array was the solution and the index was preserved.
Used this rather un-elegant method to convert from array to object `json_decode(json_encode($data))`, but it worked.

**UPDATE**

The problem was **not** the `filter` method within the `Illuminate\Http\Resources\ConditionallyLoadsAttributes` class, but rather because of a merge (using `array_merge`) just before returning the dataset. Removing this operation before returning the array (no longer an object) return the index properly.

Answer (score 0):

I also dealt with this problem.

In Laravel 8 the keys are lost because of method `removeMissingValues` in the same trait `Illuminate\Http\Resources\ConditionallyLoadsAttributes`. This method returns `array_values` function for **numeric keys** which only returns values but not keys.

However you can create a new resource class which will extend `JsonResource` and add property `preserveKeys`